# How can I remove "Also on" from Disqus?

Tags: disqus

I have tried all the solution available on web to hide that comments section, but none of them help them to sort this issue. I want to hide the "Also on" section from disqus on my site. Can anyone suggest the viable solution?

[image]

I have tried unchecking this, but have no effect.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry It was my mistake. I added wrong shortname in my disqus config.. That's why unchecking Discovery option.